# Lift a div out of the page on hover without disturbing other divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve a tooltip like effect but by using the existing label.

I have labels (in the form of material design chips) that when hovered should display all of the possible truncated text (if it fits on the screen). And without disturbing the other divs.

[this text fits] [this text doesn't...] [hello]

should look like something like this on hover:

[this text fits] [this text doesn't fit in]llo]

Keep in mind the labels have a background color, so just allowing it to overflow won't do.

My idea was to set the chip position to absolute and then add an invisible before element with the width of the chip. However, I can't get it to work in css.

html:

```
<div id="items">
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
  <div class="chip">this text is to long to fit</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.chip:hover {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  max-width: 100%;
}

.chip:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/heYgb/3/

My question:

How can I achieve a tooltip like hover effect using a div itself without disturbing siblings?

**EDIT:**

perhaps tooltip isn't the right word here. because I want to actually just "lift" the existing div up and expand it to full size without moving other divs (so overlapping).

Comment: Why don't you try "title" attribute? Doesn't that satisfy your requirement?

Comment: I don't want an actual tooltip. I want to "lift" the div out of the page (expand to fit the full text, give it a shadow)